# Genome-wide methylation analysis: sources of technical error?

Tags: bioinformatics, genomics, dna-methylation

We are doing a genome-wide analysis of methylation via bisulfite sequencing for an insect species. Previous experimental techniques have suggested the presence of methylation in this organism, including an AFLP analysis using methylation-sensitive restriction enzymes and a differential expression analysis using a methylation inhibitor.

Our bisulfite sequencing data, however, is giving us essentially no evidence of methylation. If this finding is true, it will be a pretty big deal. But before we go down that path, we want to make sure we've counted out all sources of technical error.

- First, we wondered if the bisulfite treatment failed, but quickly determined that this would not explain the result. If the C --> T conversion had failed at an extremely high rate, you would expect to see methylation all over the place. That's the opposite of what we're seeing, which is essentially no methylation.
- Second, we wondered if there was some kind of "overexposure" issue in the bisulfite treatment that caused even methylated Cs to convert to Ts. We found a paper describing this phenomenon<sup>[[1]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/nar/gkn691)</sup>, but reports we can find suggest this happens at a low (<10%) rate, which cannot explain our data.
- Third, we wondered if perhaps there was an issue with the reads mapping to the genome, we got at least 70% mapping efficiency for each BS-seq sample, so that can't be it either.

Are there any other sources of technical error we should consider and check for before believing this result?

---

1. [**Genereux DP, Johnson WC, Burden AF, Stöger R, Laird CD** (2008) Errors in the bisulfite conversion of DNA: modulating inappropriate- and failed-conversion frequencies. *Nucleic Acids Research*, **36**(22):e150, doi:10.1093/nar/gkn691.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/nar/gkn691)

Comment: This sounds very interesting. Could you provide a link to the paper that found methylation? "Previous experimental techniques have suggested the presence of methylation in this organism,"